# The conflict with expected and actual argument

Tags: haskell

```
belongs :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]

belongs e (h:t) = if ( h == e) then [] else belongs e t
belongs e [] = [e]




nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
nub l = nub' l [] 
    where 
        nub' [] new_list = new_list
        nub' (x:xs) new_list = (nub' xs ((\ e new_list ->  
            case (belongs e new_list) of
            []    ->  new_list
            (h:t) ->  (h:new_list))(x new_list)))
```

> Couldn't match expected type `[a]` with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]` In
>   the return type of a call of `nub'` Probable cause: `nub'` is applied to
>   too few arguments In the expression: `nub' l []` In an equation for
>   `nub`:
>
> ```
>  nub l
>   = nub' l []
>   where
>       nub' [] new_list = new_list
>       nub' (x : xs) new_list
>         = (nub'
>              xs
>              ((\ e new_list
>                  -> case (belongs e new_list) of {
>                       [] -> ...
>                       (h : t) -> ... })
>                 (x new_list)))
> ```
>
> Couldn't match expected type `[a0] -> [a0]` with actual type `[a1]` In
>   the second argument of `nub'`, namely `[]` In the expression: `nub' l []`
>   In an equation for `nub`:
>
> ```
> nub l
>   = nub' l []
>   where
>       nub' [] new_list = new_list
>       nub' (x : xs) new_list
>         = (nub'
>              xs
>              ((\ e new_list
>                  -> case (belongs e new_list) of {
>                       [] -> ...
>                       (h : t) -> ... })
>                 (x new_list)))
> ```

Why it doesn't work? I cannot understand. Please give me a hand.
The errors are understandable but I don't know their causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to force a function call with the lambda and the extra parenthesis `((\e new_list -> ...)(x new_list))`? If so, that doesn't work for one, and even if that syntax would work then your parenthesis would be mismatched.

Forego the 'attempted function call' and the lambda and just use `x` and `new_list` directly in `nub'`, or if you really want to rename use a `let e = x in` to bind `e`. That should fix the type errors.

If you really want the lambda, then you should know that function application is done using spaces and not parenthesis, so like `(\x -> x + 1) 3`.